# Is symbolic link to ~/something dependent on logged user?

Tags: symbolic-link

if I run command:

```
ln -s ~/user/relative/path /absolute/path
```

and then log under different user, that does not have user/relative/path in it's home directory, will the link be somehow broken or unreachable?

Thank you for your answer :).

Comment: Do you mean ~ by itself, or ~user?  Be careful not to mix them.

Comment: By '~', I mean shortcut for '/home/currently_logged_user' directory. I don't know what ~user should mean.

Comment: `~` expands to the current user home dir. `~user` expands to the home dir of the user named "user"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for yourself:

```
% ln -s ~/one two
% ls -l two
[...] two -> /home/rmano/one
```

The command `ln` does not even see the `~`  char --- it is expanded by the shell.

Now, to **use** the link the new user must have the appropriate permissions on the real path.

You *can* put a literal `~` in the link, but then it will not work, at least not in linux --- environment variables like `$HOME` are not expanded when the kernel resolves symlink.

See:

```
% cd 
% touch a1
% ln -s $HOME/a1 a2
% ln -s '$HOME'/a1 a3
% ls -l a?
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rmano rmano  0 Mar 21 13:49 a1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano 15 Mar 21 13:49 a2 -> /home/rmano/a1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano  4 Mar 21 13:50 a3 -> $HOME/a1
% cat a2
% cat a3
cat: a3: No such file or directory
```

There is some OS that has this characteristics (I think that one version of FreeBSD did that, as well as some unix I used on Apollo workstations --- not sure though) which is called **variant symlink**.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888809/environment-variables-in-symbolic-links